# Duplicate Symbol - Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, dynamic, frameworks, duplicates, symbols

I am trying to make a framework of code from NASA that is written primarily in Objective-C with some C.  I intend to use the framework in a project that is written in Swift.

I am making a framework where the Mach-O Type is Dynamic Library

When I ported the code over and resolved a bulk of the deprecations, I came up with an error that has stumped me when getting to the linking portion.

```
duplicate symbol ___gl_pqHeapInsert in:
/Users/.../Objects-normal/arm64/priorityq-heap.o
/Users/.../Objects-normal/arm64/priorityq.o
```

There are actually 6 of these errors.  I'll just focus on this one (`___gl_pqHeapInsert`).

Here are what I see as the relevant pieces of the code where this is referenced.

From **priorityq-heap.h**

.
.
.

```
#define pqInit(pq)      __gl_pqHeapInit(pq)
#define pqInsert(pq,key)    __gl_pqHeapInsert(pq,key)
#define pqMinimum(pq)       __gl_pqHeapMinimum(pq)
```

.
.
.

From **priorityq-heap.c**

```
/* Include all the code for the regular heap-based queue here. */
#include "priorityq-heap.c"

/* Now redefine all the function names to map to their "Sort" versions. */
#include "priorityq-sort.h"

.
.
.

/* really __gl_pqHeapInsert */
/* returns LONG_MAX iff out of memory */

PQhandle pqInsert( PriorityQ *pq, PQkey keyNew )
{
  long curr;
  PQhandle free;
.
.
.
```

}

For **priorityq.c**

```
PQhandle pqInsert( PriorityQ *pq, PQkey keyNew )
{long curr;
if( pq->initialized ) {
    return __gl_pqHeapInsert( pq->heap, keyNew );
  }    
.
.
.
```

Observations

- The original code (from NASA's svn) works well as it creates a static
  library (libWorldWind.a) that is embedded into the sample project.  My goal was to extract this as a framework and use in a Swift project. (Original
  code is at [SVN for NASA Worldwind(iOS)](https://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWindIOS/WorldWind/))
- This error (duplicate symbols) is common when when incorrectly importing a ".m" in an import statement.  However, this does not seem to be the case in the project.
- libtess is the library of function to do general polygon tesselations that is giving these duplicates during linking.

Any help would be appreciated with understanding what is getting duplicated.

Comment: Perhaps you are linking the static library and framework at the same time..

Comment: Hmmm... I extracted the raw code into a new project and did not bring over the static library target. Thanks for your input ... I'll check though, but I do not think there is any reference to that static library in the original project.